Gauss's method and Todd's process for generating Machin-like formulas
I've recently taken an interest in Machin-like formulas, i.e., formulas of the form:
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} q_i \arctan{\frac{a_i}{b_i}}$$
Where $q_k\in \mathbb Q$, $a_k,b_k\in \mathbb N \setminus \{0 \} $ for all $k$, and $|a_k/b_k|<1$ for all $k$. 
I've read Wetherfield's article "The Enhancement of Machin’s Formula by Todd’s Process," where he describes both "Gauss's method" and "Todd's process", used to create Machin-like formulas. I've read the article, but I'm struggling with understanding the algorithm behind these methods. 
I would like to know if there are any other sources or explanations behind these methods that might describe them better. Moreover, I would like to know if other methods are used to generate Machin-like formulas. 
Thank you all in advance!

You may enjoy this lovely old website: http://www.machination.eclipse.co.uk/

That is an interesting site (written by Wetherfield and Chien-lih), though it hasn't been updated and it looks terrible, it does outline Todd's process. Unfortunately, it does not describe Gauss's method.

Todd's Process is the most intuitive way to understand the construction of such formula, so my answer won't explain the process better than Wetherfield's article. Either way, I paraphrase the process, and give an alternative processes afterwards:
We first determine if a given integer $n$ is reducible by determining if the largest prime factor, $P$, of $n^2+1$ is less than $2n$. If true, then there exists another integer $I$ with $I<2n$ such that $P$ is also the largest prime factor of $I^2+1$. Then, the quotient
$$\frac{n+i}{(I \pm i)^a}=c+di$$
where $a$ is the multiplicity of $P$, the $\pm$ is determined by whether $n \mp I$ is divisible by $P$ (I again refer to Todd's article for the proof) and the common factors of $c,d$ have been cancelled. This yields a new complex number $c+id$ where the largest prime factor of the squared moduli $c^2+d^2$, say $\hat{P}$, is less than $P$. This process is then performed recursively until we end up with an irreducible term, or the complex part vanishes.
I show this with an example: Consider $n=4443$ such that $n^2+1=2 \times 5^3 \times 281^2$. Clearly $281<2 \times 4443$, so $n$ is reducible. Finding $I$ now involves finding a solution in $(I,k)$ of the Diophantine equation
$$ I^2+1=281k$$
which has the "smallest" solution $(I,k)=(53,10)$. Thus $I^2+1=2 \times 5 \times 281$, and by noticing that $n+I=4443+53=2^4 \times 281$, we consider the quotient
$$\frac{4443+i}{(53-i)^2}=\frac{79+3i}{50}$$
implying that $c+di=79+3i$. Doing this again we find that $79^2+3^2=2 \times 5^5$ and thus $P=5$ which obviously implies that $I=2$. Now $79+3 \times 2=5 \times 17$, so we consider the quotient
$$ \frac{79+3i}{(2-i)^5}=-1+i$$
Thus, we have the quotient
$$ \frac{4443+i}{(53-i)^2(2-i)^5}=C (-1+i)$$
for some constant $C$, and our Machin-like identity generated from Todd's Process becomes
$$\frac{3 \pi}4 =\arctan(1/4443)+2\arctan(1/53)+5\arctan(1/2)$$
or, using more compactified notation:
$$3[1]=[4443]+2[5]+2[53]$$
Then, Gauss' Method is in fact equivalent in a sense to applying Todd's Process to several $n$ whose squared moduli share common factors (again, Wetherfield's example shows this very well).
Now, because of Dodgson's formula, all methods of generating Machin-like formula necessarily involve prime factorizations. But, there are other "primitive" methods. Consider for example $a/b$ to be a ratio of integers that approximate $\pi/4$ relatively well, then we obtain
$$ \frac{\pi}4 = a \arctan(1/b) \pm \arctan(\alpha/\beta)$$
where the ratio $\alpha/\beta$ can be explicitly calculated by taking tangents on both sides (and the $\pm$ is decided by whether we round up or down when finding $a$). Also, since $\arctan(1/x) \approx x$, the value of $\alpha/\beta$ goes to zero as $b$ grows large (though slowly). Then, choose $n$ to be the closest integer to $\beta/\alpha$ and consider the Machin-like formula
$$ \frac{\pi}4 = a \arctan(1/b) \pm \arctan(1/n) \pm \arctan(\hat{\alpha}/\hat{\beta})$$
Where the $\pm$ are based on whether we are rounding down, and of course are not the same. This process will actually terminate, and will thus always result in a Machin-like formula. Lehmer considered this approach when he defined the Lehmer measure in 1938, where he wrote
$$[1]=7853[10000]-[545261]-\ldots$$
Which is the process outlined above.
